# Resolve ivy dependencies through gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

How can I tell gradle to download some dependencies and when they are downloaded? For example this is my code:

```
configurations {
    ivydep
}

repositories {
    ivy {
        url "http://my.ivy.repo/ivyrep/shared"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ivydep "eu.company:MyList:1.0.1"
}

task resolve << {
    println 'configurations.ivydep.singleFile: '+configurations.ivydep.singleFile
    // dependency is a zip so I need to unzip it
    copy {
        from zipTree(configurations.ivydep.singleFile)
        into "${buildDir}/temp"
    }
}
```

I want gradle to download dependencies when `resolve` task will be called but how can I do it? THe problem is that gradle sometimes downloads dependencies and sometimes not. As I understand gradle caches is. How can I tell gradle to download dependencies programically or how to set dependency on ivy module?

Comment: do you mean you want to force it to download every single time?

Comment: I want to tell gradle 'download dependency A only when B task will be called', something like 'lazy dependency resolving'. I just want to control it when dependency are downloaded.

Comment: Hey Patryk, gradle resolves dependencies lazy by default. In gradle a configuration like your "ivydep" is what we call a lazy filecollection. once you reference the files of this collection the dependencies are materialized (that means downloaded if not already in the gradle cache). In your sample above the dependencies declared in ivydep are just materialized during the execution of the "resolve" task.

Comment: So if I will call `configurations.ivydep` gradle will resolve this dependency?

Comment: No. A configuration is resolved as late as possible, such as when iterating over its files or when accessing the `singleFile` property.

Comment: A simpler way would be to use the `--refresh-dependencies` flag whenever you actually want it to recalculate and download the dependencies. If that fits your requirement.